# In a series! what is the best way of removing the last element

Tags: rebol, rebol3

What is the most succinct way of removing the last element in a Rebol series?

Options I have found so far are

```
s: "abc"
head remove back tail s
```

and

```
s: "abc"
take/last s
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here I wrote a REMOVE-LAST function,

```
remove-last: func [
    "Removes value(s) from tail of a series."
    series [series! port! bitset! none!]
    /part range [number!] "Removes to a given length."
] [
    either part [
        clear skip tail series negate range
    ] [
        remove back tail series
    ]
]
```

Example use:

```
b: [a b c d e f g]
remove-last b ;== [], 'g removed, tail of the series return.
head remove-last/part b 2 ;== [a b c d], 'e and 'f removed
```

It returns the tail of the series to be able to use in following situation;

```
b: [a b c d e f g]
head insert remove-last b 'x  ;== [a b c d e f x]
```

Answer (score 3):

Define "best".  Highest performance?  Most clarity?  What is it you want the expression to return at the end, or do you not care?  The two you provide return different results...one the head of the series after the removal and the other the item removed.

If you want the head of the series after removal, you need `take/last s` followed by `s` to get that expression.  Comparison:

```
>> delta-time [
    loop 10000 [
        s: copy "abc"
        take/last s
        s
    ]
]
== 0:00:00.012412

>> delta-time [
    loop 10000 [
        s: copy "abc"
        head remove back tail s
    ]
]
== 0:00:00.019222
```

If you want the expression to evaluate to the item removed, you'd need to compare `take/last s` against something convoluted like `also (last s) (remove back tail s)`... because also will run the first expression and then the second...returning the result of the first:

```
>> delta-time [
    loop 10000 [
        s: copy "abc"
        take/last s
    ]
]
== 0:00:00.010838

>> delta-time [
    loop 10000 [
        s: copy "abc"
        also last s remove back tail s
    ]
]
== 0:00:00.024859
```

etc.

If you don't care about the result, I'm going with `take/last`.  If you do care about the result and want the head of the series, I'm going with `take/last s` followed by `s`.  To me that reads better than `head remove back tail s`, although it's an aesthetic choice.  It's still faster, at least on my netbook.

If you want the tail of the series at the end of the expression, `remove back tail s` is surprisingly similar in performance to `take/last s` followed by `tail s`.  I'd say the latter is more explicit, and probably preferable, in case the reader forgets the return convention of REMOVE.

And `also last s remove back tail s` looks terrible, but is a reminder about `also`, which is pretty useful and easy to forget it's there.  FWIW, it performs about the same as using an intermediate variable.

Comment: So perhaps **REMOVE/LAST** would be nice to have in Rebol here?   This could also allow (for eg) `remove/last/part s 2` to remove last 2 `things` from series.

Comment: @draegtun An interesting idea, we can [discuss it in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/291/rebol-and-red).  Historically, Rebol native operations are not a strictly symmetric or orthogonal set of operations.  While adding elements has **INSERT** and **APPEND** there's no **REMOVE** native counterpart which automatically acts on the back.  The motto *"Inspired by theory, informed by practice"* implies that things like `remove/last/part s 2` just haven't come up that often so people live with `remove/part skip tail s -2 2` if it comes up.  It's ugly, but maybe not common enough to care?

Comment: I think that **REMOVE** can/could be seen as a corollary to **TAKE** in that both work on the *series* and leave the *index* untouched.  Food for thought?